# How to stop Django "app not found" error?

Tags: python, django

When I run `python ./manage.py sql grading` my django site comes up with:

```
Error: App with label grading could not be found. Are you sure you INSTALLED_APPS setting is correct?
```

I have the app grading with __init__.py and everything, and my INSTALLED APPS is:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'teachline.courses',
    'teachline.grading',
)
```

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found what was going wrong. I ran `python manage.py shell` and tried to `import teachline.grading.models`. It turned out I had some problems with importing modules. I fixed those and now `python manage.py sql grading` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a directory which contains `teachline` in your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable? It may be necessary to `export PYTHONPATH="."` to make things work.

Comment: I tried changing PYTHONPATH, but it didn't work. Running `python manage.py sql courses` works; `grading` is the only app it doesn't work for.

Comment: How did you create your app? By using `startapp` command? Does it have models.py inside app directory.

Comment: And does it have `__init__.py`?

Answer (score 0):

Does the file `teachline/grading/__init__.py` file exist in the pythonpath.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'teachline.courses',
    'teachline.grading',
)
```

Try to add just 'grading'

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.sites',
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'courses',
        'grading',
    )
```